# Confusion about electrical potential difference

Tags: electrical-resistance, voltage

[image]

I am confused why voltage is same across parallel circuit as shown above where wire is an ideal conductor. The voltage at top part of the resistor $R_1$ and $R_2$ is same. $R_1$ has higher resistance than $R_2$. Now suppose electron passes through $R_1$ then shouldn't electron spend more energy on $R_2$ that is let's say electron after passing through $R_1$ still has 0 energy left but after passing $R_2$ it still has some energy left so shouldn't voltage difference be different across different resistor with different resistance? I have seen some post where people say because top part and bottom part of parallel circuit is connected to resistor thus voltage is same but I don't see why is this true. I see this from potential energy perspective. How do physicist know voltage is exactly same across these two resistor?

Comment: The electric potential in an ideal conductor is the same everywhere in that conductor. Therefore the electric potential at the "top" of the resistors is the same, just as at the bottom, and so the voltage across the resistors, i.e., the electric potential difference across the resistors, is the same.  I'm a little confused about your statement about an electron going through R1 and then R2.  An individual electron in the circuit will go through only one of the resistors.

Comment: @march I mean electron1 goes through $R_1$ and electron2 goes through $R_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy loss of a specific charge (like an electron) on passing through a resistor depends not on the resistance, but on the voltage difference.  That voltage difference itself depends on the current.

If the path through one of the resistors wasn't removing all the available energy from the charges, they would continue to be accelerated, increasing the current.  That increasing current would raise the voltage difference in the resistor, draining more energy.

The process is a feedback loop that converges to a steady-state where the voltage drop across both resistors is equal to the voltage gain from the battery.  Because of the differing resistances, the currents through $R_1$ and $R_2$ will be different, but the voltage drop will be the same.

Comment: So why does being steady state implies same voltage drop across those resistors?

Comment: Yes, similar.  Sort of like falling at terminal velocity.  Speed increases until drag exactly matches weight.  Here current increases until resistor voltage drop exactly matches battery EMF.

Comment: I hope I am understanding it correctly. If voltage drop of those resistors are not same implies the energy is not fully dissipated then electron acclerates. Then like drag force resistor decrease the speed of electron eventually until it is steady-state. This mean top part and bottom part is same in terms of voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm  not sure if I understand your question correctly, however I assume your talking about the potential difference across each of the 2 distinct paths being constant. You can think of it as "even though one has a larger resistance, the current is different for each case, making the total potential difference the same.

The proof:

In the absence of changing magnetic fields, the electric field is Conservative

$\nabla × \vec{E} = 0$

$\vec{E} = - \nabla V$

From the fundamental theorem of gradients

$\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}} \nabla V \cdot \vec{dl} = V(t_{1}) - V(t_{0})$

Substituting

$\int - \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} = V(t_{1}) - V(t_{0})$

The potential difference between 2 points is only dependant upon the start and end of the line integral and not the path in-between. Thus means the PD across both paths, with the same start and end point is the same. This path doesn't even have to follow the wire.